# Event listener not working - proper placement or syntax?

Tags: flash, addeventlistener

In a Flash object I have an item (called widgit1) that I'm trying to attach an event listener to. I just want Flash to execute a JavaScript alert though no matter where I place it on the time line, regardless of which layer and regardless of what syntax I've found none of the many MANY combinations I have tried have worked.

Here is the ActionScript I have...

widgit1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.mouseOver,ohhai);

function ohhai() {getURL("javascript:alert('oh hai!')");}

Comment: It should be `function ohhai(event:MouseEvent):void`. But you should get an error for that, are you using the flash player debug version?

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned the syntax error. Beyond that however you want to use ExternalInterface for communication between ActionScript and JavaScript:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
function ohhai(e:MouseEvent):void
{
// etc

}
```

Comment: "The class or interface 'MouseEvent' could not be loaded."

After some reading it turns out that AlexW's code requires ActionScript 3, I'm using 2 with Flash 8.

jhocking, off-topic, I've already confirmed the way I'm executing JavaScript works though I also use what you refer to for other things.

Also I do NOT need to pass any parameters or events, I merely have to execute a JavaScript command. The issue with the event listener still stands.

Comment: I haven't used ActionScript 2... I recommend using 3 though from what I've hard it's a bit harder to learn but way more powerful. You can get the Flex compiler for free and can get debugger etc too. It's possible that you might be having a security issue with what you're doing? Flash has quite a lot of that.